# Most Idiomatic Way to Rearrange a List of Dict While Removing Duplicates?

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list of dictionaries, each containing two identical keys with possibly different values:

```
list_of_dicts = [
{'a': '1', 'b': '1'},
{'a': '4', 'b': '4'},
{'a': '1', 'b': '1'},
{'a': '3', 'b': '0'},
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'},
{'a': '4', 'b': '99'}
]
```

I want to rearrange this structure so that the values of one of the keys is a key, and the value is a dictionary of the other values (more keys will be added to these dictionaries later).

I also want to retain the different values for those keys (without duplicates). So the result should look like:

```
{'1': {'b': {'1', '2'}}, '4': {'b': {'4', '99'}}, '3': {'b': {'0'}}}
```

The purpose of this is to

- remove duplicate values of 'a'
- be able to call a dict based on the keys 1,4,3 in this example
- retain the information held in the other key-value

This is the code I wrote to do this:

```
newdict = \
{d['a']: { #for each unique a value, build a dict with key b containing a set of all b values
            'b':{d['b']} | {another_d['b'] for another_d in list_of_dicts if another_d['a'] == d['a']}
            } \
for d in list_of_dicts}
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more idiomatic or cleaner way to write this? I tried using d.get() but I don't think it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {"a": "1", "b": "1"},
    {"a": "4", "b": "4"},
    {"a": "1", "b": "1"},
    {"a": "3", "b": "0"},
    {"a": "1", "b": "2"},
    {"a": "4", "b": "99"},
]

out = {}
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for k in d.keys() ^ "a":
        out.setdefault(d["a"], {}).setdefault(k, set()).add(d[k])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'1': {'b': {'1', '2'}}, '4': {'b': {'99', '4'}}, '3': {'b': {'0'}}}
```